# Get N latest distinct record from the collection [Mongodb]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
const eventSchema = new Schema({
  id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  serviceName: String,
  event: {
    type: { type: String, required: true },
    subType: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  properties: Object,
  created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now() },
})
```

Above is the schema for `Event` Model. how can i get the latest N no of distinct record ( distinct by `type` & `subType`) with `created_at` date?

Comment: can you share some sample data and expected output?

Comment: @varman, 
https://imgur.com/mgBA7p5.png
please look the above url for sample data.

As you see in the screenshot above there are two documents with same `type` and `subType` (type: VIDEO, subType: PLAYED) . we must only get one latest event type & subType. 

Output may be similar to 
```
[
{
event: {
type: 'EBOOK',
subType: 'ACCESSED'
},
created_at: date
},
{
event: {
type: 'VIDEO',
subType: 'PLAYED'
},
created_at: date
}
]
```

Comment: can you confirm again in your sample data, there are no any similar type and subType documents.

Comment: @turivishal, added sample data in the question.